# How do I calculate the probable success rate in a game: x + random(12) => y

Tags: ruby, probability

I'm trying to program a line of Ruby code that calculates the probable success rate of a simple skill test in a text adventure game. The test is "if x + random(12) => y then". How do I calculate the probable rate of success of this statement being true in Ruby?

In the game the player has certain skills and will occasionally have to test those skills plus a random number to get greater or equal to a given difficulty number. I want to calculate the success rate percentage of being able to win that skill test.

As an example in the adventure game your trying to track some animal through the jungle. To do this you must test your skill at tracking. If for example you have a tracking skill of 3 and you add a random number between 1-12 to that, you need to score at least a 9 or greater to succeed. Basically: Skill + random(12) => Difficulty_Number. I want to show a Success Rate percentage before they play to see what their chance of succeeding will be.

So in Ruby, what would be the algorithm to figure out the chance of success with my current Skill score? Thanks!

Comment: Correct me if a misread, but if you have 3 + random in 1..12, and due to those number you'd need a 9, isnt that a 50% chance every time?

Comment: Kudos for wanting to give the player an estimate of their chances, rather than forcing them to work it out for themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this.

```
def success_rate(skill, success_level, random_range=12)
  delta = success_level - skill

  return [100 - (delta.to_f / random_range * 100), 100].min.round(2)
end
```

Comment: It seems odd to embedd the `round(2)` inside, when really what you want to do is round the result before returning it. `[100 - (delta.to_f / random_range * 100), 100.0].min.round(2)` would ensure it's always a float, and always rounded. The `return` is extraneous in Ruby if it's the last line, as it's implicitly returned anyway.

Comment: @tadman thanks for the `round(2)`, I left it in the middle by mistake. About the `return`, I am aware of it and I like to use it for multi-lines function. I think it gives the code a better readability.

Comment: Ruby's going to return the last line wether you like it or not, but if you want to be clear as a matter of personal preference, that's fine. It just comes across as a bit quirky, kind of like an accent from someone who's used to another language where it's required.

Comment: @tadman going further, you could complain I added a blank line in the middle ;) There is many cases I don't use `return`. I however do not feel I need to avoid it. If I was to remove the `return`, I would have store the result in a variable and write this variable at the end. Maybe because I am used to work with *not really good* programmers.

Comment: Hello again. I'm wondering how would I enter the above equation into a scientific calculator. The ruby code worked great but when I try to work out the expression on my calculator I get the wrong answer. It should be 50 and it's coming out wrong. I know I'm not entering it right. I tried it as: 100-(delta/12*100) but that's all wrong on the calculator.